# How to parse API response in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on integrating Scale's API and having trouble parsing the response in my Rails Controller.

The params posted to the controller from Scale look something like:

```
Parameters: {"task"=>{"task_id"=>"589253a3b36b2d...1fe68", "created_at"=>"2017-02-01T21:31:15.607Z", "completed_at"=>"2017-02-01T21:31:15.612Z", "callback_url"=>"http://...", "type"=>"categorization", "status"=>"completed", "instruction"=>"Is this company public or private?", "params"=>{"allow_multiple"=>true, "categories"=>["NCI....
```

My controller method:

```
 def create
   # check authorization
   callback = $scale.build_callback params, 'task', callback_key: request.headers['scale-callback-auth']

   response = callback.response # Response content hash (code and result)
   task = callback.task     # Scale::Resources::Task object


   return nil if ScaleWebhook.exists?(task_id: task.task_id)
   ScaleWebhook.create!(task_id: task.task_id, response: task.response)    
end
```

In the console, when I get a `Scale::Resources::Task` I can just do something like `task.task_id`. An example object:

```
#<Scale::Resources::Task:0x007fad81573e70 @task_id="589252b2b36b2d060061fd19", @type="categorization", @instruction="Is this company public or private?", @params={"allow_multiple"=>false, "categories"=>["public", "private"], "attachment"=>"http://www.google.com/", "attachment_type"=>"website"}, @urgency="day", @response=nil, @callback_url="http://www.example.com/callback", @status="pending", @created_at=2017-02-01 21:27:14 UTC, @completed_at=nil>
```

But my Rails controller is doing this:

```
ScaleWebhook Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "scale_webhooks" WHERE "scale_webhooks"."task_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["task_id", "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fd680575130>"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "scale_webhooks" ("task_id", "response", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["task_id", "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fd680575130>"], ["response", "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fd68058d578>"], ["created_at", 2017-02-01 21:31:15 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-01 21:31:15 UTC]]
```

As you can see, it's inserting `#<ActionController::Parameters` into the DB, instead of the value. I'm guessing this has something to do with rails' strong parameters, but I've tried a couple variations of permitting and even permitting all parameters as a test, and I'm still not able to access anything beyond `#<ActionController::Parameters` .

I'm using the `build_callback` method provided by the `scaleapi-ruby` as it validates the auth_key sent from Scale, but I guess I don't really need to use it to parse the response further, as something like `params['task_id']` works.

**UPDATE**:
It looks like the model was set to serialize all params, with the serialization off, I get the following error:

```
TypeError (can't cast ActionController::Parameters):
app/controllers/scale_api_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

This is line 13:

```
return nil if ScaleWebhook.exists?(task_id: task.task_id)
```

Commenting out line 13, I have the same problem where I get something like `#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fd6815317b8>` instead of the actual task id.

**UPDATE 2:**

Using binding.pry, I got:

```
#<Scale::Resources::Task:0x007fd919aa1f78
 @callback_url=nil,
 @completed_at=nil,
 @created_at=nil,
 @instruction=nil,
 @params={},
 @response=<ActionController::Parameters {"category"=>["Blackish", "Sherlock"]} permitted: false>,
 @status=nil,
 @task_id=
  <ActionController::Parameters {"task"=>{"task_id"=>"58925f...00620894", "created_at"=>"2017-02-01T22:20:25.921Z", "completed_at"=>"2017-02-01T22:20:25.927Z", "callback_url"=>"...", "type"=>"categorization", "status"=>"completed", "instruction"=>"Is this company public or private?", "params"=>{"allow_multiple"=>true, "categories"=>["Arrow", "Last Man on Earth", "The Real O'Neals", "Blackish", "Sherlock", "Riverdale"], "attachment"=>"...", "attachment_type"=>"image"}, "is_test"=>true, "urgency"=>"day", "metadata"=>{"name"=>"...", "user_id"=>1}, "response"=>{"category"=>["Blackish", "Sherlock"]}}, "response"=>{"category"=>["Blackish", "Sherlock"]}, "task_id"=>"58925f29b36b2d0600620894", "controller"=>"scale_api", "action"=>"create", "scale_api"=>{"task"=>{"task_id"=>"58925f29.....600620894", "created_at"=>"2017-02-01T22:20:25.921Z", "completed_at"=>"2017-02-01T22:20:25.927Z", "callback_url"=>"...", "type"=>"categorization", "status"=>"completed", "instruction"=>"Is this company public or private?", "params"=>{"allow_multiple"=>true, "categories"=>["Arrow", "Last Man on Earth", "The Real O'Neals", "Blackish", "Sherlock", "Riverdale"], "attachment"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com...", "attachment_type"=>"image"}, "is_test"=>true, "urgency"=>"day", "metadata"=>{"name"=>"...", "user_id"=>45}, "response"=>{"category"=>["Blackish", "Sherlock"]}}, "response"=>{"category"=>["Blackish", "Sherlock"]}, "task_id"=>"58925f29b...b2d0600620894"}} permitted: false>,
 @type=nil,
 @urgency=nil>
```

Comment: instead of passing the whole `params` to the API, filter it to just the attributes you need. i.e. `params.select { |k,v| k.in? [ 'key1', 'key2'] }`

Comment: @maxple I'm not clear how this would solve the issue. I'm trying to parse the response from the API, not pass anything to the API, but can't seem to access anything in the response

Comment: did you check using `binding.pry` that your task object (Scale::Resources::Task) is alright?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I just did, but I've never used it to debug before, so not entirely sure what I'm looking at. Some of those things should not be nil, I don't think.

Comment: My guess is it's still a strong parameters issue. I have to run out for an hour or so, but will play with that a bit more.

Comment: It is not a strong parameters issue because that occurs when you are trying to pass a bunch of args to create or update using params hash. Look at your Scale::Resources::Task, it is clearly not what you are expecting out of it. Try doing `ScaleWebhook.create!(task_id: params[:task][:task_id], response: params[:task][:reponse])`, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused due to a bug in the gem. More information can be found on [this issue](https://github.com/wikiti/scaleapi-ruby/issues/2).

> The problem was related to a conflict between how Rails handles parameters (`ActionController::Parameters`) and how this library manages them (`ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`).
>
> The previous version of this gem used wrongly the `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` constructor in [Scale::to_hash](https://github.com/wikiti/scaleapi-ruby/blob/v0.2.0/lib/scale.rb#L37). Now, the bug is fixed with some checks on the same [method](https://github.com/wikiti/scaleapi-ruby/blob/v0.2.1/lib/scale.rb#L37).
>
> If you can't update the gem (or don't want to), you may want to pass a hash instead to `scale.build_callback` by using `ActionController::Parameters#to_unsafe_hash`:
>
> ```
> callback = $scale.build_callback params.to_unsafe_hash, 'task',
>                                  callback_key: request.headers['scale-callback-auth']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ActionController::Parameters are meant to work as the only data being passed to ActiveRecord builder methods. (create!, create, new, etc) When you say

```
ScaleWebhook.create!(task_id: task.task_id, response: task.response)`
```

you are not passing an ActionController::Parameters object to `.create!`. You are passing a regular hash, one of who's values happens to be an instance of ActionController::Parameters. Since that column is set to accept serialized data, AR sees that instance as just another object to serialize, and shoves it's raw form into the column.

You need to make it so the only data passed to `.create!` for mass assignment is the ActionController::Parameters object in task.response. You can still set other values in a block.

Additionally, task.task_id seems to be returning a ActionController::Parameters as well. You probably want to pull the task id (the *real* task_id, the "58925f...00620894" data) out by saying `task.task_id.require(:task).require(:task_id)`

So in sum, you probably want something like:

```
ScaleWebhook.create!(task.response) do |scale_web_hook|
  scale_web_hook.task_id = task.task_id.require(:task).require(:task_id)
end
```

At this point, you may get assignment/mass assignment errors depending on your model. Make sure to permit all the data you want to allow through for mass assignment onto your model.

I'm not familiar with the Scale API, but I would recommend reading through the documentation a bit. There may be a more elegant way of getting to the task_id.

Comment: This is a gem that wraps the Scale API, they don't have a Ruby SDK. I'm still getting `can't create instance of Singleton` errors now. I have access ot the params hash as it comes through, I think I'll just rebuild the object from there and not rely on the gem's builders to do it.

Comment: That's probably best. It's best practice to have a layer of separation between 3rd party apis and your app.